# Text partially disappearing in many applications after unlocking on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, window-manager, window, text, unlock

Ever since I updated to the new Xubuntu version (16) I have two behaviours:

1. sometimes I have to switch tty after unlocking the Laptop to make my mouse cursor appear again. I heard it is related to the Intel driver and that it might get fixed in a later version, so I'm hoping for that. The workaround of switching ttys is ok though.
2. This is the reason I created this question. After unlocking I sometimes run into the scenario of disappearing text elements in some of my application windows. Most applications are effected (thunderbird, terminal), others (Chrome, Virtualbox) are not. The problem looks like this:
   [Missing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LorVH.png)

Are these two issues related to one another? What I tried so far was:

- refreshing fonts cache: fc-cache -f -v
- xrefresh
- restarting the window manager: xfwm4 --replace
- switching tty
- sudo restart lightdm
- startxfce4

Problem is: I can't see if the commands show errors, since the output of the terminal is corrupted as well. Does anyone have an idea where to look for a solution to this?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Filed a bug report regarding issue number 2:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1622614

Comment: Any updates? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem got fixed just a few days ago with a new version of package xserver-xorg-video-intel. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604

But this fix made the 2nd problem worse. The missing text issue got much more frequent after this. I couldn't find a bug report for this yet.

Comment: thanks for the update, I will reboot my system asap. I hope the second issue will be fixed as well... Any idea who to address regarding this issue?

Comment: Ok, the second issue has definitely worsened. I'll probably file a bug report for that.

Comment: @Benedikt , If you create a new bug report, please post the url of it here

Comment: I posted it under my initial post ;)
For clarity: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1622614

Answer (score 0):

it seems that updating the intel drivers actually fixed the issue. At least there is no indication for a fix in the bug reports.